# How to make \dashrightarrow as short as \mapsto?

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to render three arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\mapstochar\dashrightarrow$ \\
$\mapsto$\\
$\rlap{$\mapstochar\relbar$}\hspace{-.1em}\mapsto$
\end{document}
```

They are all of different length:

[image]

How to make them all of the same length (the same as `\mapsto`) and preferably get rid of `mathfonts`?

BTW, try to change document class to `acmart` and the first two arrows will be of the same length.

Comment: The last one is easier: `\mathrel{\mspace{3mu}}\mapstochar\mathrel{\mspace{-3mu}}\mapsto`

Comment: @egreg thanks! somehow, in `acmart` package, the first one is rendered correctly. what do they do with it?

Comment: Apparently they have a dash arrow than `amssymb`. Note that `acmart` uses Libertine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `trimclip`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dmapsto}{\mapstochar\mathrel{\mathpalette\dmapsto@\relax}}
\newcommand{\dmapsto@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen\z@}{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
  \settoheight{\dimen\tw@}{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
  \sbox\z@{%
    \makebox[\dimen\z@][s]{%
      \clipbox{0 0 {0.4\width} 0}{\resizebox{\dimen\z@}{\height}{$\m@th#1\dashrightarrow$}}%
      \hss
      \clipbox{{0.69\width} {-0.1\height} 0 {-\height}}{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
    }%
  }%
  \ht\z@=\dimen\tw@ \dp\z@=\z@
  \box\z@
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\mmapsto}{%
  \mathrel{\mspace{2mu}}\mapstochar\mathrel{\mspace{-2mu}}\mapsto
}

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt

\fbox{$\dasharrow$}

\fbox{$\dmapsto$}\fbox{$\mapsto$}

$x \dmapsto y$

$x \mapsto y$

$x \mmapsto y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `dasharrow` of `amssymb` is scaled to be as wide as `\rightarrow`, but the arrow tip is clipped off and replaced by the standard arrow tip. Care is taken to get the same bounding box.

For `\mmapsto`, we exploit that `\mapstochar` has zero width, so we can set one shifted to the right, then back up and typeset `\mapsto`.

Comment: If you look closely at your adjusted dash arrow, the ends of the arrowhead have bits nipped off.  Probably not distinguishable at 10pt.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fixed. The segments don't have round caps, but I can't see how to avoid it. Maybe `amssymb2` with arrow tips matching Computer Modern's? :-)